# list() but 'str' object is not callable error in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am working in python 2.7.3,and tried to read a csv file `PNG_Files_R.csv` containing the following information:

```
"Group","Sample","T0" \n
"HereausCPC","61","sample06_1_T0-Subvolume-resample_scale-1_x.png"
```

I would like to read the file in each row cell by cell, except the first row. but I could never use list() to get the numbers of rows, it reports ''str' object is not callable'

```
import Image
import os,csv
path_working="/media/Research/TEST_Program/PNG_Files"
path_now=os.getcwd() 
os.chdir(path_working)
csv_filename='PNG_Files_R.csv'
f = open('PNG_Files_R.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f) 
rows = list(csv.reader(f))
lineNum = len(rows)
for rowNum in range(1,lineNum):
    print rows[rowNum][0]
```

I restart python and then no error pops

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You really need to format your code properly in the question, especially if it's Python where whitespace is critical.

Comment: It's not the complete, relevant code, is it?

Comment: sorry about the format problem, I did put 4 space ahead of each code,but the code block did not represent as it should be.would please tell me how did you edit it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have likely previously assigned a string value to a variable named `list` in the same module. Choose a different name for your variable and the problem will go away.

Comment: my script is pretty short only import and then those codes.perhaps you mean `list(csv.reader(f))` ?

Comment: @user3817800 Please edit the question to include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Thank you , I started to use python from this weekend and tried lots of things but forgot to clean the variable list.

Comment: I had a similar situation in which I had assigned a string to 'type.' This meant that calling type() on functions didn't work because Python interpreted 'type' as a string value.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reader and jump over first line by calling `next()` on it.

```
csv_filename='PNG_Files_R.csv'
with open(csv_filename, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

In case you really want to get all the rows into list of values:

```
csv_filename='PNG_Files_R.csv'
with open(csv_filename, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    reader.next()
    rows = list(reader)
```

Then you can access the records by index like `rows[3]` (if there is so many records).

This solution is anyway assuming you did not redefine `list` in your previous code, it shall collect all the records from
csv file ignoring the first header line.

Comment: Thanks iterator is really nice method, however I need to call some specific rows later.

Comment: @user3817800 Added modification, which provide list of all the rows.

Comment: This is more elegant and effective, thanks for the update, I will use it.but I did redefine the `list`before this script.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `list` as a variable name.

```
In [1]: list = "foo"

In [2]: list(1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1860a40b9973> in <module>()
----> 1 list(1,2,3)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```